# How to repetitive / looping Sound from Resource file in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, loops, audio, qt5

Is there any simple way how to play repetitive / looping Sound from Resource file in Qt?

For single sound play I use this and it works fine:

```
QSound::play(":/Sounds/swoop.wav");

(WORKS)
```

But this not:

```
QSound sound(":/Sounds/swoop.wav");
sound.play();

(DOES NOT WORK)
```

Or even this:

```
QSound sound (":/Sounds/swoop.wav");
sound.setLoops(QSound::Infinite);
sound.play();

(DOES NOT WORK)
```

I think I should use QSoundEffect class:

```
QSoundEffect effect;
effect.setSource(":/Sounds/swoop.wav");
effect.setLoopCount(QSoundEffect::Infinite);
effect.setVolume(0.25f);
effect.play();
```

But QSoundEffect class doesn't work with Resources files which I have to use.
I've tried to find a way around with QFile but unsuccessfully.
I use Qt 5.3.1
Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide complete functions/methods, or preferably a full [MSVC](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, to code in C++, you need to understand the lifetime of variables and objects. Otherwise you'll have hard time making sense of any C++ code.

Comment: With QSoundEffect you have to use "qrc:/Sounds/swoop.wav" instead of ":/Sounds/swoop.wav" to make it work with resources. I just banged my head against a wall with this.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess from this limited code snipets but are you sure that created `QSound` lives long enough? `QSound::~QSound` calls `QSound::stop` after all.

**EDIT:**

There are 3 ways to use QSound, lets see all of them in action:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QSound>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(first()));
    connect(ui->pushButton_2,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(second()));
    connect(ui->pushButton_3,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(third()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::first()
{
    const QString path = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << path;
    QSound sound(path);
    sound.play();
}
```

The problem with `MainWindow::first` is that right after `sound` object is created and its' method `play` is called it is destroyed (it goes out of scope). Since `QSound` is called in destructor this will most likely have no chance to play any part of your sound.

```
void MainWindow::third()
{
    const QString path = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << path;
    QSound* sound = new QSound(path);
    sound->play();
}
```

This way you will have your sound played but there is memory leak, so you will need to add some form of memory management to destroy `sound` object **after** sound is finished playing. If you go to `QSound` source you will see that there is slot called [deleteOnComplete](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmultimedia/source/8e6ffcc6afe984cc9598184c9a71cdf377674597:src/multimedia/audio/qsound.cpp#L230). Unfortunately it's private so your on your own here.

```
void MainWindow::second()
{
    const QString path = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << path;
    QSound::play(path);
}
```

The last case is to use static `play` function. And it's the easiest way also. If you check how is it implemented, it uses that private slot I mentioned previously and connects it to signal from private `QSoundEffect` instance data member. You can find working example [here](http://tomaszklak.pl/tmp/qsound_gui.tar.gz).

So this are your options if you want to play sound using `QSound`. If you want to use `QSoundEffect`, there is nice [example](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmultimedia/source/8e6ffcc6afe984cc9598184c9a71cdf377674597:src/multimedia/audio/qsound.cpp#L114) in `QSound::QSound` how to construct `QSoundEffect` so that it will use resource.

Comment: They are not snippets, this is content of my own method "void MainWindow::PlaySound()" Anyway the main question is, how to do it anywhere in the code. I found out that QSound class is not very recommended, so I am trying to use QSoundEffect @TomaszKlak

Comment: It this is all there is in your methods then what I have wrote is true - your instance `sound` will be immediately destroyed upon exit from that method and you will most likely not hear anything. Allocating that object on heap and deleting it later will fix your problem.

Comment: You know, I am beginner and this didn't tell me much, code would be better. Could you give me any example? @TomaszKlak

Comment: @OndřejKrál Those *are* snippets. If you save them in a .cpp file and try to build, you get compiler error, after all...

Comment: Thank you for the correction because that is exactly what matters here. @hyde

Comment: @OndřejKrál I detect sarcasm, but yes, it it *does* matter. The snippets in isolation make it impossible to say what the problem is. The guess of this answer is probably correct, but as long as the code you show is as incomplete as it is, it's just a guess.